# How do i use healing items in vigor?

Tags: vigor

So, I was just playing a match in vigor, and I got shot up pretty bad. I tried to use some disinfectant I had to heal, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. How do I use healing items in this game? Also, I am on Xbox if that is a factor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hold the left bumper to bring up the consumable wheel
2. Use the right stick to select the item you want to use
3. Once selected, use the right trigger to use the selected consumable

Healing consumables are automaticly applied to you when using the trigger.
To heal a teammate or random stranger, stand close enough to them untill you see "heal xxx" when using the right trigger.

Late answer, i know. But still hope it helps future players.